# Is there a better way to swap string without a placeholder

Tags: python, regex, string, replace, swap

I have a string:

```
>>> s = 'Y/NOUN/dobj>_hold/VERB/ROOT_<membership/NOUN/dobj_<with/ADP/prep_<X/PROPN/pobj_>,/PUNCT/punct'
```

And the aim is to change the position of `Y/` to `X/`, i.e. something like:

```
>>> s.replace('X/', '@@').replace('Y/', 'X/').replace('@@', 'Y/')
'X/NOUN/dobj>_hold/VERB/ROOT_<membership/NOUN/dobj_<with/ADP/prep_<Y/PROPN/pobj_>,/PUNCT/punct'
```

Assuming that there'll be no conflict when doing the replacement, i.e. `X/` and `Y/` is unique and will only happen once each in the original string.

**Is there a way to do the replacement without the placeholder?** Currently, i'm swapping there position by using the `@@` placeholder.

Comment: May be use `\0` instead of `@@` to reduce chances of conflict.

Comment: Yes, there are ways. Are you using Python?

Comment: @wiktor yes, python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, an easy way using a regex is via a lambda in the `re.sub` replacement part where you can evaluate/check texts captured with capturing groups and select appropriate replacement:

So, `(X|Y)/` (*I assume `X` and `Y` are potentially multicharacter string placeholders, otherwise use `([XY])`*) should work:

```
import re
s = 'Y/NOUN/dobj>_hold/VERB/ROOT_<membership/NOUN/dobj_<with/ADP/prep_<X/PROPN/pobj_>,/PUNCT/punct'
print(s)
print(re.sub(r"(X|Y)/", lambda m: "Y/" if m.group(1) == 'X' else 'X/' , s))
```

Output:

```
Y/NOUN/dobj>_hold/VERB/ROOT_<membership/NOUN/dobj_<with/ADP/prep_<X/PROPN/pobj_>,/PUNCT/punct
X/NOUN/dobj>_hold/VERB/ROOT_<membership/NOUN/dobj_<with/ADP/prep_<Y/PROPN/pobj_>,/PUNCT/punct
```

Comment: Thanks @wiktor! Just the right kind of regex solution I was looking for.